# Scale large centered images to fit html table height

Tags: html, css, css-tables, fluid-layout, image-scaling

I'm trying to restrict the height of images within a table. The reason for the table is to allow these images to be aligned vertically and horizontally to the center of the page. The problem I have is  that images larger than the browser height disappear of the bottom of the page enlarging the table, I'd like the image to have `max-height:100;` and scale to fit. It works with the width, but not the height.

Here's what I have so far...

```
<div id="table">
<div id="cell">
<img src="image.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
```

and

```
html, body{
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#table{
display:table;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

#cell{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
background-color:#ccc;
}

img{
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you use some JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/boyce/mJSxx/

Comment: @Abody97 ...I've managed to get it working with a JS plugin but also wondered if I could implement purely with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this without using a `table`. Here's the basic outline, HTML:

```
<body>
    <img src = "image.jpg"/>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto; /*make sure it's centered both vertically and horizontally*/
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

And a little jsFiddle demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/M44qU/). Note that `body` must have `position: relative;` for this to work.

I hope this helped!